# I want to get the parents id from my container in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have an issue, so i created a mxml container file called Container1.mxml that has

`<mx:VBox>`
     `<mx:Label text="{textName}" />`
   `</mx:VBox>`

so when i call it
   it will be something like

`<container:Container1 id="hello" />`

then the id will appear in my Label text.

appreciate it in advance. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't just use `text="{this.id}"`?

Inside Container1.mxml, have a creation complete listener that calls this function:

```
protected function _handleCreate(e:Event):void {
    myTextLabel.text = this.id || "unknown";
}
```

Comment: awesome thank you. sorry i am really new in flex. both work excellent thank you again